# Make bootable iso with grub chainloading

Tags: grub, iso-image, grub2

My parents' pc has windows 7's boot manager installed at MBR and grub2 is installed on /dev/sda2 (booting linux on /dev/sda2). I want to make a bootable cd so that when booted from it just chainloads into the boot manager on the second partition. I assume using grub rather than grub2 for this will be simpler, using the configuration

```
timeout=0
hiddenmenu
default=0
title grub2 (/dev/sda2)
        rootnoverify (hd0,1)
        chainloader (hd0,1)+1
```

I know I can make a bootable linux cd in various ways, but that is not what I want. I just want to put grub/grub2 on the cd, no kernels or programs.

The question is how do I make the iso file? I have found some references to installing on a floppy or usb disk, but all those assume the device is present when running the grub install commands. A iso file is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general concept is that, from a Linux box, you want to create a image file, format it with iso9660 with El Torito boot support, and specify the GRUB images to `genisoimage`.

A well-documented tutorial is [on osdev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bootable_El-Torito_CD_with_GRUB_Legacy). You can skip the section where it tells you to supply a kernel image, because that's only if you want to boot a kernel that's on the CD.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I was looking for. I have some problem with the configuration, because grub stops at a prompt when booting (where I can enter the rootnoverify+chainloader+boot commands). But that's another problem, the "how to create a simple boot cd" issue is solved.